# dataSource does not display the properties value in mat-cell

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to display the data form service to Data Table.I can view the elements from USER_DATA inside the console but not in html.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2lIM.jpg
  This is my component code:

```
export class DashboardComponent  {
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'company'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<User[]>; 
  constructor(private userService: CustomService) { 
    const USER_DATA: Array<User[]> = [];

  this.userService.getUser().subscribe((user) => {
           this.USER_DATA = user;
  });

   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(USER_DATA);
}
```

Data table code:

```
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Progress Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.email}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
            <mat-header-cell    *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Phone</mat- 
                header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.phone}}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Company</mat- 
               header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.company.name}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        </mat-row>
      </mat-table>
```

Comment: MatTableDataSource<User[]>; shoult be <User>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `users` is `User[]` try this

```
export class DashboardComponent  {
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'company'];
  dataSource=new MatTableDataSource<User>();
  constructor(private userService: CustomService) { 
      this.userService.getUser().subscribe(users => this.dataSource.data=users);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me more info what I was doing wrong in my example ?Thanks !

Comment: You were creating empty Datasource on init. Later on either you was not updating the content (i dont know internals of MatDataSource), or you was simply not triggering rerendering of the table. I am no expert here.